# Zero-cross detection phase delay BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, phase-shift, zero-crossing

[image: circuit]

Low-speed output:
[image: At low speed output]

High-speed output:
[image: At High speed output]

In the above circuit, output channel 1 (yellow) is a Hall signal and channel 2 (Green) is the ZCD output.

There is a phase delay between channel 1 and channel 2 of 15° at low speed, and the phase shift increases to 24° when speed is increased. When the speed changes from low to high 15-24° 10° phase delay occurs. Can anyone tell me a good way to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the delay consistent in time?

Comment: delay time is change depending on Motor speed .

Comment: Check if the delay is consistent with the R4*C1 time constant.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a low voltage sine wave signal to read zero crossing, and there is also an RC delay from R11 and C1. So that will cause a delay between the actual zero crossing and what you observe on the scope. You probably don't need such a large capacitance for noise filtering.

Another way to compensate for the zero crossing delay is to add a small negative bias on the (-) input of the op-amp so that it will trigger earlier.

You may also have some positive feedback from the output of the op-amp to obtain hysteresis and clean edge triggering, but this will also cause some phase delay.

For additional help, more information will be required, such as actual voltage levels and frequency, and specifications for the allowable phase shift between the Hall sensor signal and the ZC detector.

Comment: sorry correct circuit image is now attached

Comment: The suggestions in my answer still apply.

Comment: phase delay time is change depending on Motor speed. starting low speed 15 deg phase shift .Increase the motor speed phase delay also 24 deg increase so hysteresis method is not working. 15-24 deg shift  is occurred depend on motor speed. so can tell me a good way to solve this issue?

Comment: The 10k resistance with 10 nF capacitor (TC=100 uS) might account for 1 degree at 26 Hz and 5 degrees at 143 Hz, but I doubt it. What op-amp are you using, and what Hall sensor? Can you show the waveform at the inputs of the op-amp? Could be instability of the virtual neutral reference, or PWM noise.